# Vector of threads corrupting my string. C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to c++. I decided to work on it because it seems badass. Here is my issue. I want to execute multiple files simultaneously. I went with thread for that. And it works when only doing one which defeats the purpose. When I put the threads into a vector it seemed to corrupt my characters. I'm not sure if that is what's going on. I'm new to c++. Here is my code.

```
        // Un vector para los threads y multithreading
    vector<thread> threads;

    // Ha un loop sobre los argumentos
    for (int i = 0; i < genData.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i % 3 != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        string filePath = genData[i];
        string diplomaName = genData[i+ 1];
        string diplomaDetails = genData[i+ 2];

        string commandArgs = " '" + filePath + "' '" + diplomaName + "' '" + diplomaDetails + "'";
        string command = "php file.php " + commandArgs;

        // exec(command.c_str());
        threads.push_back(thread(exec, command.c_str()));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
```

That's the logic of my vector of threads. Here is the exec function:

```
string exec(const char *cmd)
{
    array<char, 128> buffer;
    string result;
    unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&_pclose)> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe)
    {
        throw runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)
    {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `genData[i+ 1]` and `genData[i+ 2]` *will* go out of bounds when `i == genData.size() - 1` and `genData.size() - 2` (in the last and second to last iterations). Instead of that clumsy `i % 3` check, why not use `i += 3` in the loop itself? And of course check if `genData.size()` is a multiple of `3` before the loop.

Comment: You have dangling reference in `exec`. It takes a pointer to underlying data of `command` variable which is local inside for loop. Change `exec` to take string, instead const char*, and just pass command to `thread(exec,command)`.

Comment: what happens to object created by declaration string variable when you reach end of for-loop body? Do you know what a lifespan of object is?

Comment: *I am new to c++* -- And the topic you should stay away from *until* you know the basics of C++ language, object lifetimes, etc. is multithreaded programming.